# Haskell: pass tuple and secondary value into Boolean-Returning Predicate for "any"?

Tags: list, haskell, boolean, tuples

I have a function in which I pass in a Point and a Polygon (see type definitions below).

`pointIsOnBorder` (see below) takes a Point and a Polygon, and determines whether that Point is on one of the borders of the given Polygon.

```
type Point = (Double, Double)
type Polygon = [Point]

pointIsOnBorder :: Point -> Polygon -> Bool
pointIsOnBorder a ps = if (any onLineSegment(a) (breakPolygonToLines ps)) then True else False
```

In the above example, `breakPolygonToLines` correctly takes a list of Points (aka Polygon) and returns a list of Point tuples. Ex: `breakPolygonToLines` returns `[((2.0,3.0),(4.0,3.0)),((4.0,3.0),(5.0,6.0)),((5.0,6.0),(2.0,3.0))]` for an input of `[(2,3), (4,3), (5, 6)]`.

From the snippet above, `onLineSegment` takes a Point and a Point tuple and determines whether the Point exists on the given Point tuple (aka line segment).

```
onLineSegment :: Point -> (Point, Point) -> Bool
```

**However, I'm experiencing errors by passing in each Point tuple into `onLineSegment`**. Is the syntax `any onLineSegment(a) (breakPolygonToLines ps)` valid?

Edit: added a lot more details; please see above.

Comment: Do you mean something like this `any (determineSomething a xs)`? What is the type of `determineSomething`?

Comment: `determineSomething :: a -> (a, a) -> Bool`

Comment: What do you want to use as the tuple?

Comment: The type of myFunct should be `a -> [(a,a)] -> Bool`, right?

Comment: `onLineSegment(a)` is the same as `onLineSegment a`. In this context it is treated as the second argument to `any`: `any onLineSegment(a)` == `any onLineSegment a`. Accept the answer that suggests to put the brackets differently, grouping the argument the way you want: `any (onLineSegment a)`

Comment: You shouldn't remove the code example/question body. It's now really hard to determine what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to answer without knowing what exactly your functions are doing. It seems that `any (onLineSegment a) (breakPolygonToLines ps)` is what you're looking for. `(onLineSegment a)` fixes the first argument of the function and gives a function from tuple to Bool.

Relevant wiki page: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application